# как имитировать нажатие клавиш клавиатуры?

Tags: python

цель задачи, **открывать хром** и автоматически **писать запрос** в поисковой строке.
нужно как то **открывать хром** через **python** и **писать запрос тоже через python**

Comment: посмотрите в сторону селениума

Comment: нет, мне нужен код, да и селениум я пробовал

Comment: что значит нужен код ?

Answer (score 0):

В Selenium есть операция `send_keys`. Вот ее и используйте.